# jQueryUI Tabls how to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

in Ruby on rails 3.1+ this is my code

_form.html.erb:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

test.js.coffee

```
$("#tabs").tabs()
```

in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require_tree .
```

Why don't tabs show?? I try to write in application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("test!");
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  }
```

test message show but tabs don't render...thank's in advanced for help me

Aesis.

Comment: view source of the page and see if jquery and jquery  ui is loaded or not...

Comment: Yes..loading correctly. <script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you need the content for each tab. Every anchor points to the content of its tab using the href attibute. You need to put a div called tabs-1 and a div called tabs-2 for this to work.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aesis OK, the thing is, the divs have to be inside of your "tabs" container... fixed my HTML and it works.